# why is my facebook application keeps refreshing after sending invitations?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i'm using this code to invite friends to my facebook application

```
<?php 

     $app_id = "12165444444444444";

     $canvas_page = "http://www.domain.net/facebook/app/";

     $message = "Would you like to join me in this great app?";

     $requests_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?app_id=" 
            . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page)
            . "&message=" . $message;

     if (empty($_REQUEST["request_ids"])) {
        echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $requests_url . "'</script>");
     } else {
        echo "Request Ids: ";
        print_r($_REQUEST["request_ids"]);
     }
```

?>

but after sending the invitations the page keeps refreshing in like infinit loop

what is wrong with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `request_ids` parameter will only be added to the URL if the user has just accepted an application request, the following will happen:

1. A user visits the page, and then is redirected to a request dialog (`$requests_url`).
2. The user either invites friends or cancels the dialog. They are redirected back to your application's canvas page (`$canvas_page`).
3. Since `$canvas_page` does not contain the `request_ids` parameter, the user is redirected to a request dialog (see #1).

Without testing, I suspect that since a requests dialog was just created (and closed), Facebook is automatically redirecting to the `redirect_uri`, thus causing infinite redirects.

Comment: i don't know how did i miss that, i should redirect to the Canvas Page NOT the Canvas URL. thanks Martey.